# RegEx - match where second letter is not first letter and third letter is first letter

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will identify expressions where the first and third letters are the same, but different to the second letter.

e.g. match against the following expressions:

```
abaxyz
bzbaaadsfsdf
```

but not

```
aaaxyz
abcdefg
bbbaaasdf
```

I've tried back-references, but can't make "NOT match 1"

Imagining something like
^(?[a-z]){!P1}{P1}

where P1 is the capture of the first letter, {!P1} is "anything except the first capture" and {P1} is "same as the first capture".

I have more complex requirements to follow, such as "first letter, not first letter, not first or second letter" (i.e. 3 distinct letters at the start)

e.g.

```
abcdef
```

but not

```
abbxyzz
```

So if anyone can point me to the proper regex constructs for referencing and matching/excluding previous matches/captures, that would much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: word matching patterns identified by word boundaries ... **PCRE**: [`/\b(?<letter>\p{L})(?!\k<letter>)\p{L}\k<letter>.*?\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/1hKkSS/1) ... **ECMAScript**: [`/\b(?<letter>\p{L})(?!\k<letter>)\p{L}\k<letter>.*?\b/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/1hKkSS/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^([a-z])(?!\1)[a-z]\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AH0Ml6/2). *Details*:

- `^` - [start of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `([a-z])` - [Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1: a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?!\1)` - a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is Group 1 value immediately to the right of the current location
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `\1` - (an [inline backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)) Group 1 value.

If you want to match the rest of the word, append the `[a-z]*$` to the regex.

Comment: So: Match a-z as group 1. Peek ahead - if group 1 is found, reject expression. Match a-z (which can't be group 1's value). Match group 1 again.
Is that an appropriate english translation?

Comment: @NeilMoss That is correct.